# How to query Latitude/Longitude data from InfluxDB (Flux) for display in Grafana Geomap panel?

Tags: grafana, influxdb, flux-influxdb

I have data from a vehicle's route in InfluxDB with geotagging in the variables `Latitude` and `Longitude`. I would like to display the data as Markers in a Grafana Geomap panel.

My query for the data in Grafana looks as below:

```
from(bucket: v.defaultBucket)
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "1F4F8F26")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "Latitude" or r["_field"] ==  "Longitude")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: median)
  |> yield(name: "median")
```

This query lets me plot the data as in the following picture:
[image]

In table form, the data looks as follows (note how I can switch between display Latitude and Longitude separately):
[image]

The problem is that when I try to use a Geomap panel, nothing is displayed as per below:
[image]

I have tried also with a restructuring of my data into a `Time, Latitude, Longitude` format via below query:

```
from(bucket: v.defaultBucket)
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "1F4F8F26")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "Latitude" or r["_field"] ==  "Longitude")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: median)
  |> yield(name: "median")
  |> pivot(rowKey:["_time"], columnKey: ["_field"], valueColumn: "_value")
```

However, this still does not enable me to display the points as markers in Grafana. Any inputs are welcome.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to remove the aggregation function.

I'm using this query with Geomap:

```js
import "influxdata/influxdb/schema"

from(bucket: "fleet")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> range(start: r._measurement == "points")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._field == "lat" or r._field == "lon" or r._field == "alt" or r._field == "speed")
  |> schema.fieldsAsCols()
  |> group()
  |> sort(columns: ["_time"])
```

Seems that geomap does not handle well grouped data, therefore pivoted data are ungrouped (and then `sort` is needed to get correct order).

Comment: This seems to do the trick, awesome! Next step will be for me to try and make the 'route layer' work (alpha layer) and get the new crosshair functionality to function (which should track the GPS map vs. other panels when hovering a specific point in time